# Is it possible to format a value that we received from an array to make it something else

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, discord.js

My title doesn't really explain itself that much, so here is an explanation.

Currently, I have a command on my Discord bot that shows me Mojang's servers and their status.

Here is the code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { get } = require("https");

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
    //const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member

    get("https://status.mojang.com/check", (res) => {
        const { statusCode } = res;
        if (statusCode != 200) {
        res.resume;
        }
        res.setEncoding("utf8");
        let rawData = '';
        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
            rawData += chunk;
        });
        res.on("end", () => {
            try {
                const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);

                console.log(parsedData[0]);
                console.log(parsedData[1]);

                message.channel.send({
                    embed: {
                        color: 0xe61616,
                        title: `Mojang API Status`,
                        fields: [
                          {
                            name: "minecraft.net",
                            value: parsedData[0]['minecraft.net']
                          },
                          {
                            name: "session.minecraft.net",
                            value: parsedData[1]['session.minecraft.net']
                          },
                          {
                            name: "account.mojang.com",
                            value: parsedData[2]['account.mojang.com']
                          },
                          {
                            name: "authserver.mojang.com",
                            value: parsedData[3]['authserver.mojang.com']
                          },
                          {
                            name: "sessionserver.mojang.com",
                            value: parsedData[4]['sessionserver.mojang.com']
                          },
                          {
                            name: "api.mojang.com",
                            value: parsedData[5]['api.mojang.com']
                          },
                          {
                            name: "textures.minecraft.net",
                            value: parsedData[6]['textures.minecraft.net']
                          },
                          {
                            name: "mojang.com",
                            value: parsedData[7]['mojang.com']
                          }
                        ],
                        footer: {
                            text: `${bot.user.username} - Copyright 2021 - 2025`
                        }
                    }
                });

                console.log(parsedData);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e.message);
            }
        });
            }).on("error", (err) => {
                console.error(err.message);
            });
}
```

The result is what the array says, so `minecraft.net green`

```json
[
  { "minecraft.net": "red" },
  { "session.minecraft.net": "green" }
]
```

But what I want is that when it shows, it's "minecraft.net: ". Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Don't like to an external site with code, embed it here on stackoverflow and try to make your code as minimal as possible with only the most relevant part. We don't need your entire bot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can format a value. As the response you receive from the API is an array of objects, where the key is the server name and the value is the colour/status, you could just check the value and if it's the string `green`, you replace it with a green emoji, and if it's the string `red`, replace it with a red one.

You could also use [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) instead of struggling with the built-in `http` module.

To get the key and value for each object, you can use the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method. It returns an array of key-value pairs, so you'll need to grab the first one. To get the fields, you can iterate over the response and for each object, return a new object, where the `name` is the server's name, and the `value` is the emoji (based on the green/red value):

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
// ...
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://status.mojang.com/check');
    const json = await res.json();
    const statusEmojies = {
      green: '',
      red: '',
    };
    const fields = json.map((server) => {
      const [name, status] = Object.entries(server)[0];
      return {
        name: name,
        value: statusEmojies[status],
      };
    });
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(0xe61616)
      .setTitle('Mojang API status')
      .addFields(fields);

    message.channel.send(embed);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    message.channel.send('Oops, there was an error. Try again later!');
  }
};
```

[image]

You could also just create an array of strings instead and use it in the description. At least, I think it looks a bit better this way:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
// ...
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://status.mojang.com/check');
    const json = await res.json();
    const statusEmojies = {
      green: '',
      red: '',
    };
    const fields = json.map((server) => {
      const [name, status] = Object.entries(server)[0];
      return `${statusEmojies[status]} ${name}`;
    });
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(0xe61616)
      .setTitle('Mojang API status')
      .setDescription(fields.join('\n\n'));

    message.channel.send(embed);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    message.channel.send('Oops, there was an error. Try again later!');
  }
};
```

[image]

Comment: As an aside, `Object.fromEntries(data.map(Object.entries).flat())` is a neat way to make a single object out of that array-of-objects.